# Grouping by calculated field not working as expected

Tags: sql, sas

In the below query, I'm attempting to group by ID, and a calculated date field.  I'd like to do this in a single proc sql, it works if I do 2 separate SQL calls, but for some reason I'm not able to group by my calculated column.  I even tried to change the group by to: "group by 1,2" and that didn't work.  I've confirmed that both date fields are SAS dates, not date/time fields.  Am I missing something completely obvious?

```
proc sql;
create table work.test as 
select distinct
    t1.id,
    (case when t1.date1>t2.date2 then t2.date2 else t1.date1 end) format mmddyys10.0 as new_date, 
    sum(t1.amt) format dollar8.2 as new_amt
from 
    work.cr_2 t1
    inner join work.cr_1 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
group by
    t1.id,
    calculated new_date;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002294533.htm) is pretty clear on this:

> CALCULATED enables you to use the results of an expression in the same
>   SELECT clause or in the WHERE clause. It is valid only when used to
>   refer to columns that are calculated in the immediate query
>   expression.

That doesn't say `GROUP BY`.  So, use a subquery or repeat the logic -- and remove the `distinct` while you are at it:

```
proc sql;
  create table work.test as 
    select tid, new_date,
           sum(t1.amt) format dollar8.2 as new_amt
    from (select t1.*,
                 (case when t1.date1 > t2.date2 then t2.date2 else t1.date1 end) format mmddyys10.0 as new_date
          from work.cr_2 t1 inner join
               work.cr_1 t2
               on t1.id = t2.id
         ) tt
    group by id, new_date;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  Perhaps there was something else wrong?

```
data cr_2 ;
  input id date1 amt ;
  informat date1 yymmdd10. amt $dollar32.;
  format date1 yymmdd10. ;
cards;
1 2015-12-01 100
;;;;
data cr_1 ;
  input id date2 amt ;
  informat date2 yymmdd10. amt $dollar32.;
  format date2 yymmdd10. ;
cards;
1 2015-12-01 100
;;;;

proc sql;
create table work.test as 
select t1.id
     , case when t1.date1>t2.date2 then t2.date2 else t1.date1 
       end format yymmdd10. as new_date
     , sum(t1.amt) format dollar8.2 as new_amt
from work.cr_2 t1
inner join work.cr_1 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
group by t1.id
       , calculated new_date
;
quit;

proc print; run;
```